# sed stops fetching the remaining content after a linefeed character is encountered

Tags: regex, linux, sed

```
sed -nE "s/(IMAGE)(.*)/\1\2/p" somefile > sfh.raw
```

somefile contains random ASCII as well as binary data after the image. The above sed command works, if there is no newline binary data in the file. If there is a newline it just outputs only until the new line, ignoring the rest of the file.

Is there a way we can make sed (.*) capture everything including the new line and continue until the end of the somefile content.

```
IMAGE254656
   dsfdfdl;flkdfldsfkdsfkdlsfdfldfkdsfo;dsfkldsfdsfsd
```

Comment: Try `grep -Eoz 'IMAGE.*' somefile > sfr.raw` (if you have a GNU `grep`)

Comment: `sed 's/(foo)(bar)/\1\2/'` is pointless since it is an identity transformation.

Comment: `sed` operates line by line, I do not think you can make it work across lines, or read the file as binary.

Comment: `sed` can work across lines; it is not designed to work with binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `awk` for this:

```
awk '/^IMAGE/{i=1}i' somefile
```

`awk` processes a file line by line and allows you to set variables and check contents and lots of other very fancy stuff for each line.

This script checks each line to see if it starts with `IMAGE`. If so, it sets variable `i` to `1`. Then it checks to see if `i` is set. If so, it does its default behavior of printing the line.